# Translate strings into comparison operations in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have html select form in my asp.net app:

```
<select class="form-control" name="ageOption" asp-for="AgeOption"  value="Equals">
        <option>Equals</option>
        <option>More Than</option>
        <option>Less Than</option>
    </select>
```

In the future, I want to create a query that would take these values ​ and translate them into comparison operations

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Find(int age, string ageOption)
    {
         var users = new List<User>();
         await Task.Run(() => users = session.Query<User>()
                        .Where(u => u.Age **ageOption** age);
    }
```

Comment: Does `session.Query<T>` return an `IEnumerable<T>` or an `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: @canton7 ```IEnumerable<T>```

Comment: `u => ageOption switch { "Equals" => e.Age == age, "More Than" => u.Age > age, ..... }`

Comment: @canton7 compiler throws CS0832 error

Comment: I don't know what you've written. It works here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQqn9Y

Comment: What is the actual C# data type for `session.Query<User>()`? Your error indicates it is _not_ `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with a database query, you can modify the query and then run it later:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Find(int age, string ageOption) {
    // var users = new List<User>(); // don't do this - it creates an empty List that you immediately replace below
    List<User> users;

    var q = session.Query<User>();

    switch (ageOption) {
        case "Equal":
            q = q.Where(u => u.Age == age);
            break;
        case "More":
            q = q.Where(u => u.Age > age);
            break;
        case "Less":
            q = q.Where(u => u.Age < age);
            break;
    }

    await Task.Run(() => users = q.ToList());
}
```